# What will be the function or loop structure of 50 students groups. So that they never face off when assigning them in different groups. How to solve?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, combinations, permutation

My goal is to create 4 sessions. each session has 20min of time. And I need to arrange 50 students in groups. Where each group has at most 3 members. And create this four times in 80 minutes. SO that each time each student will assign in groups with differnet students. No one will face off again.

Comment: You have forgotten to add your code.

Comment: I'm thinking about the solution. I don't have any code for this. I just want a clear concept so that I can start work with it. @quamrana

Comment: I think 20 mins specified are irrelevant?  You just need to assign 50 students in groups of max 3 , four times without anyone being repeated in same group

Comment: Make a `Student` class to represent each student and given them each a `set`. When you are filling a group with students, you can check whether a candidate for the group has already been with other students by checking their set. When a candidate is added to the group, you can add all the other students to their set to remember for the next session that they can't be in another group with those students.

Comment: Hint:  
Solve the problem for 8 students, then expand that solution to 48 students and assign the remaining two students as required by the specification

Comment: Still not clear to me. Please explain elaborately. It will help. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the right website for you. This website is concerned with specific programming problems where you have some code, but its not quite working right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot more groups than you need to solve this problem, so there are plenty of easy ways that work.

One way:

1. Divide your students into groups of 2 or 3.
2. In each group, assign numbers: one student will be number 1, one will be number 2, and if there's a 3rd, one will be number 3.
3. Arrange the groups in a circle.  At the end of each session, the number 1s stay put, the number 2s move one group clockwise, and the number 3s move two groups clockwise.

It's reasonably easy to prove that this satisfies your conditions.  For each student:

- Every student he groups with will have a different number -- every group always has a 1, a 2, and maybe a 3
- Once he groups with another student, that student will move 1 or 2 groups further away at the end of every session.
- There are 17 groups, so at either 1 or 2 steps per session, it takes 17 sessions before the student will meet either of his group-mates again.

This sort of strategy works well in a lot of cases.  If you have a prime number of groups, more groups than students per group, and more groups than sessions, then no two students will meet twice.

Comment: Thanks alot. Finally get this.